# iPhone Safari keyboard to say next vs go

Tags: ios, browser, safari, keyboard

I have a website that is optimized to work on iOS devices. But the problem is that the keyboard always says `Go` as user fills the form. How do I get the keyboard to say `Next` until the last entry on the form, where it should say `Go`? Or alternatively, how do I disable the Enter button entirely?

Again, this is a website. It works everywhere websites work: in browsers. Except I have having this particular problem in Safari on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

while changing the input type gives you some control of the keyboard layout the return key label in  IOS cannot be customized.

Answer (score 0):

Other than changing it to say Search there are no customizations available. You can disable the functionality of the button using something like this in`jQuery`:

```
$("#myForm input").live("keyup", function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode === 13) {
    $("#myForm").trigger("submit");
    }
});
```